# Why does this derived class need to be declared as a friend?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm learning C++ on my own, and I thought a good way to get my hands dirty would be to convert some Java projects into C++, see where I fall down. So I'm working on a polymorphic list implementation. It works fine, except for one strange thing.

The way I print a list is to have the `EmptyList` class return "null" (a string, not a pointer), and `NonEmptyList` returns a string that's their data concatenated with the result of calling `tostring()` on everything else in the list.

I put `tostring()` in a `protected` section (it seemed appropriate), and the compiler complains about this line (`s` is a `stringstream` I'm using to accumulate the string):

```
s << tail->tostring();
```

Here's the error from the compiler:

```
../list.h: In member function 'std::string NonEmptyList::tostring() [with T = int]':
../list.h:95:   instantiated from here
../list.h:41: error: 'std::string List::tostring() [with T = int]' is protected
../list.h:62: error: within this context
```

Here's most of `list.h`:

```
template <class T> class List;
template <class T> class EmptyList;
template <class T> class NonEmptyList;

template <typename T>
class List {
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, List<T>* l){
        o << l->tostring();
        return o;
    }
    /* If I don't declare NonEmptyList<T> as a friend, the compiler complains
     * that "tostring" is protected when NonEmptyClass tries to call it
     * recursively.
     */
    //friend class NonEmptyList<T>;

    virtual NonEmptyList<T>* insert(T) =0;
    virtual List<T>* remove(T) =0;
    virtual int size() = 0;
    virtual bool contains(T) = 0;
    virtual T max() = 0;

    virtual ~List<T>() {}
protected:
    virtual std::string tostring() =0;
};

template <typename T>
class NonEmptyList: public List<T>{
    friend class EmptyString;
    T data;
    List<T>* tail;
public:
    NonEmptyList<T>(T elem);
    NonEmptyList<T>* insert(T elem);
    List<T>* remove(T elem);
    int size() { return 1 + tail->size(); }
    bool contains(T);
    T max();
protected:
    std::string tostring(){
        std::stringstream s;
        s << data << ",";

        /* This fails if List doesn't declare NonEmptyLst a friend */
        s << tail->tostring();

        return s.str();
    }
};
```

So declaring `NonEmptyList` a friend of `List` makes the problem go away, but it seems really strange to have to declare a derived class as a friend of a base class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `tail` is a `List<T>`, the compiler is telling you that you can't access a protected member of another class. Just as in other C-like languages, you can only access protected members in your instance of the base class, not other people's.

Deriving class A from class B does not give class A access to every protected member of class B on all instances that are of type class B or derived from that type.

[This MSDN article on the C++ `protected` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e761de5s.aspx) may be helpful in clarifying.

#### Update

As suggested by [Magnus in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977927/why-does-this-derived-class-need-to-be-declared-as-a-friend/977982#977982), in this instance, a simple fix might be to replace the call to `tail->tostring()` with the `<<` operator, which you've implemented for `List<T>` to provide the same behavior as `tostring()`. That way, you wouldn't need the `friend` declaration.

Comment: Ah, ok, I think I understand. So I can access protected members of a base class within a class definition, but not "from outside," and since `tail` is an instance, doing `tail->tostring()` is coming "from outside." Right? (forgive my ignorance)

Comment: Pretty much. This MSDN article might help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e761de5s.aspx

Comment: I stumbled across this hole today. You can do this: struct voyeur : List<T> { using List<T>::tostring; }; (tail->*(&voyeur::tostring))();

Answer (score 5):

As Jeff said, the toString() method is protected and can't be called from your NonEmptyList class. But you have already provided a std::ostream& operator<< for the List class, so why dont you use it in NonEmptyList?

```
template <typename T>
class NonEmptyList: public List<T>{
// ..
protected:
    std::string tostring(){
        std::stringstream s;
        s << data << ",";

        s << tail; // <--- Here :)

        return s.str();
    }
};
```

Comment: Brilliant - that works beautifully. Thanks for the tip; I'm still not sure I'm understanding the access control issue.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, You declare List* tail as a **member** of the class NonEmptyList, that's why you cannot access it. If you want to access a protected method from base class, then you need to call base->tostring();

You are doing composition, **NOT** inheritance here.

And I am not sure why you end up this class design by converting a java project, if you inherit from a base class, your normally don't want to declare another instance of base class as your member variable. This approach doesn't look very smooth to me. I don't think you even need do that in Java.

Comment: It would make more sense (I think) if I included more code that I didn't think was germane: tail needs to be of the base class because it could be a NonEmptyList or an EmptyList. It might be doing things in an overly-complex way, but then if I wanted simplicity, I'd use STL. But it's a good point, thanks.

Comment: @J.W.: Huh? It looks like a recursive data structure combined with the Null Object pattern.

Comment: bk1e, yes, good point, I guess I didn't go through the code in detail enough.

Thanks for pointing out.